# Explicit definition of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, data-analysis

Suppose there are 6 sequences $a=(a_n)_{n\geq 0}, b=(b_n)_{n\geq 0},c=(c_n)_{n\geq 0},d=(d_n)_{n\geq 0},e=(e_n)_{n\geq 0},f=(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$, the data can be seen here: [Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18iBwTCx7LXFNTZptmoOMQfEat4imLeTciwUxHzX3gpw/edit?usp=sharing). I found out by trial and error that $a$ is defined by
\begin{align}
a_n=\lceil 970\cdot1.025^{n}\rceil.
\end{align}
It is easy to see that 
\begin{align}
c_n=\lceil(b_n/2)/5\rceil\cdot5, \\ d_n=\lceil(c_n/3)/5\rceil\cdot5, \\e_n=\lceil(d_n/4)/5\rceil\cdot5, \\ f_n=\lceil(e_n/5)/5\rceil\cdot5. 
\end{align}
I guess $b_n$ should be as well rounded to the next integer divisibly by $5$, but i do not see the explict definition. It should have something to do with $a_n$, or at least with $970$. *$b$ is growing on average relativly faster than $a$ until $n\approx 40$ then slower.*
How can i find $b$ without trial and error?

Would it be helpful to have different examples for the sequences $a$ and $b$? I mean $a'$ with $a'_0=510$ generates a sequence $b'$ with $b'_0=55$ and $a''$ with $a''_0=700$ generates a sequence $b''$ with $b''_0=70$. I can list about the first $30$ members of those sequences as well.

edit: something is not right with my formulas if $f_n=0$, but it should always mean "round to the next integer divisibly by $5$".

Comment: How do you generate these sequences?